# Bad scoping practices (global and CONSTANT) and practicality?

Tags: php

I've researched that using `global` is considered bad practice as it allows the function to execute without the variable actually being set and `CONSTANT`'s shouldn't be used for anything that is very, very static such as the number of days in a week.

The problem I'm really frustrated with is using variables in functions and *practicality*.
For instance, let's say I get the user's IP with `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` and it's needed in multiple functions. When I want to use one of those functions, I have to look back at the function and remind myself what the order was for the parameters, even though I *know* it is needed for the function.

Another instance is user information that isn't going to be changing, like their username or their age. I need to use it in multiple functions, but again I have to figure out the order of the parameters and include about 5 extra parameters for all the information, it honestly seems counter-productive to follow good practices.

Am I getting this right? Do you guys usually just include all the parameters?

Comment: If your function accepts so many parameters to work - it likely means that it does too much job

Comment: It's a user search function. Should an IP be a CONSTANT?

Comment: it's already a variable `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`

Comment: I see, I had originally thought it was faster setting it to a variable. So I guess there should always be a workaround to using bad practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find it helpful to look into the [Registry pattern](http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/the_registry).

Personally, if a method needs access to an authenticated user's details my code tends to look something like:

```
public function sayHello() {
    $user = Auth::getAuthenticatedUser();

    return 'Hello, ' . $user->getName();
}
```

Comment: I will take a look at that one sec

Comment: I like this, it's going to take some time to learn, but thanks!

Comment: Good luck! It's a lot of fun and well worth the effort :)

Comment: Static registry is an antipattern, because it introduces another form of [global state](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI). What you suggested is just masking the global state behind structure that *looks* like OOP but **IS NOT**. Let's just hope that @Adam184 did not follow your advice.

Comment: @tereško thanks! I've been doing a lot of OOP this week and I don't believe it's possible to getAuthenticatedUser statically? I don't think you can use `$this` within a static function if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: @Adam184 , the solution is to inject the authentication service (one that deals with `User` instances) where you need it. But watch the lecture that was linked .. and all the related ones. It will be good for you.

Comment: @tereško Ah yes, I got that response about a minute ago from a question I asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994171/php-passing-an-object-through-a-class. Thanks teresko for all your help :D