# PHP Passing an object through a class?

Tags: php

After restructuring my entire class layout, I'm still having trouble using multiple class instances.

```
class User {
    public $variable;
    public function getUser() {
        $this->variable = 'It works!';
        return 'bob';
    }
}

class Base {}
class One extends Base {
    public function test() {
        print_r($User->variable); // Want it to print 'It works!'
    }
}

$User = new User();
$username = $User->getUser();
if($username === 'bob') {
    $One = new One();
    $One->test(); // prints "Notice: Undefined property: One::$variable
}
```

What the above code does: The class `User` gets the username. If the username is `bob`, it will create an object `one` and try to print the variable from class `User`. In my real code, `User` is extremely intricate and passing a bunch of things with `__construct` just isn't what I'm looking for.

I think the solution (*which is why I titled this question as so*) would be to create a new class `User` within class `Base` but I just can't wrap my head around having to create a whole new object and re-initiate everything just to get the username.

Comment: I think you're confused about what `$this` means.

Comment: didn't know what to put there. I'm trying to pass the object through the class and access it somehow

Comment: I asked much the same question a long time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862399/php-access-class-inside-another-class

Comment: :O I read that question before I posted this one. I wasn't sure if it were the same thing, I will look into it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject your `User` instance:

```
class One {
    private $user;
    public function __construct(User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    public function test() {
        print_r($this->user->variable);
    }
}

$User = new User();
$One = new One($user);
$One->test();
```

This doesn't have any undue effects with regards to efficiency, as the instance is passed by reference as opposed to copied.

Comment: oh wow after testing the instance there is a lot of power in this... you can call functions and set variables through the instance. Pretty incredible. Thank you Waleed this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Adam184 This pattern is called [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), which is a pretty useful technique to know.

Answer (score 1):

The class `One` does not know about the `$User` variable and therefore can not access it.

You could either pass the variable to the class in the constructor or set it after creation of an object of the class.

```
class One extends Base {
    protected $user;
    public function setUser(User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    public function One(User $user) {
        $this->setUser($user);
    }
    public function test() {
        print_r($this->user->variable);
    }
}
```

Or (but please don't, it is bad practice) set the `$User` variable to global.

```
global $User
```

Comment: Thanks, that's why I titled the question "passing the object `User` through the `One` class".

Comment: As alternative to the 'global' option you can set `$variable` static. The you'd call `print_r(User::$variable);`. But although not so bad as 'global', still not a good practice. Use the inject option.